# muting an iframe CODE EDIT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I wouldnt normally do this however I am out of shear desperation. I have never had this much trouble implementing a feature before, however I am trying to mute an iframe with a video inside it. As you can see in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87dsjL8q/1/), this has been achieved. My problem is that I can not seem to implement this code I have already produced into my actual website where I want to use it.

Now as this is a site specific question I will show you my livelink. I will however edit the question with the relevant code after the question has been answered for future posterity of this post and to help people in the future. [LIVELINK HERE!](http://www.cambridgedesign.company/website.html)

Can somebody please explain to me why this code will not work in my site and show me how to do it?

Thank you

```
<div></div>
```

Comment: It looks like your javascript is running before the page has finished loading. Move it to the bottom.

Comment: @jrummell at the bottom of the page body section?

Answer (score 1):

Try put it in the document ready function.
 - Always keep javascript at the bottom
 - i think you should clean up your javascript

Else try this:

```
api.player.postMessage(
  '{ "method": "setVolume", "value": "0" }',
  'http://player.vimeo.com'
);
```

Comment: at the bottom of the page body section?

Comment: would it make a difference whether it was local or on a sever? lol